# Is it safe to emit a sigc++ signal in a destructor?

Tags: c++

My current project has a mechanism that tracks/proxies C++ objects to safely expose them to a script environment. Part of its function is to be informed when a C++ object is destroyed so it can safely clean up references to that object in the script environment.

To achieve this, I have defined the following class:

```
class DeleteEmitter {
public:
    virtual ~DeleteEmitter() {
        onDelete.emit();
    }
    sigc::signal<void> onDelete;
};
```

I then have any class that may need to be exposed to the script environment inherit from this class. When the proxy layer is invoked it connects a callback to the onDelete signal and is thus informed when the object is destroyed.

Light testing shows that this works, but in live tests I'm seeing peculiar memory corruptions (read: crashes in malloc/free) in unrelated parts of the code. Running under valgrind suggests there may be a double-free or continued use of an object after its been freed, so its possible that there is an old bug in a class that was only exposed after DeleteEmitter was added to its inheritance hierarchy.

During the course of my investigation it has occured to me that it might not be safe to emit a sigc++ signal during a destructor. Obviously it would be a bad thing to do if the callback tried to use the object being deleted, but I can confirm that is not what's happening here. Assuming that, does anyone know if this is a safe thing to do? And is there a more common pattern for achieving the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The c++ spec guarantees that the data members in your object will not be destroyed until your destructor returns, so the `onDelete` object is untouched at that point.  If you're confident that the signal won't indirectly result in any reads, writes or method calls on the object(s) being destroyed (multiple objects if the `DeleteEmitter` is part of another object) or generate C++ exceptions, then it's "safe."  Assuming, of course, that you're not in a multi-threaded environment, in which case you also have to ensure other threads aren't interfering.

Comment: Pretty much this- the object still exists as normal whilst `onDelete.emit()` is going off, so it's safe as long as it doesn't throw.